# On mass and velocity (relativity)

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames, mass

If I have masses of the same object at different velocities, then, is the sum of the relativistic masses we have, and the sum of the masses which we could obtain by adding velocities and putting them in the equation, the same?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is whether the relativistic mass for $\mathbf v_1$ plus the relativistic mass for $\mathbf v_2$ is the relativistic mass for $\mathbf v_1\oplus\mathbf v_2$, where $\oplus$ indicates [relativistic addition of velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula).

One way to answer this is just to try a particular example. Let's consider invariant mass $m$ and velocities $c/2$ and $c/3$ in the same direction.

The relativistic mass when moving at $c/2$ is

$$\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}m\approx 1.15m$$

while the relativistic mass when moving at $c/3$ is

$$\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2}}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt 2}m\approx 1.06m.$$

Relativistic addition of the two velocities gives

$$\frac{\frac 12+\frac 13}{1+\frac 12 \frac 13}c = \frac 57 c.$$

The relativistic mass when moving at *this* speed is

$$\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^2}}=\frac{7}{2\sqrt 6}m\approx 1.43m$$

which is *not* the sum of the previous two relativistic masses. So the answer to your question is No, because what you asked about doesn't hold in this case.

When the algebra seems to be complicated, you can always prove that two things aren't equal just by finding a single numerical case where they aren't.

By the way, the concept of relativistic mass is confusing and outdated. Today, most physicists only talk about the invariant mass. Instead of relativistic mass, they talk about relativistic energy, which is the same thing except for a factor of $c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have masses of same object at different velocities then is sum of relativistic masses we have and one which we could obtain by adding velocities and putting in equation the same.

No. For example, if a solid ball with a proper mass $M$ and a radius $R$ revolves swiftly around its axis, SRT predicts that every single ring element of this rotating sphere experiences mass increase with a Lorentz factor of the element's tangential velocity of $r\omega$:

$$dM_{\omega}= \left ( 1-\frac{r^2\omega^2}{c^2} \right )^{-1/2}dM \space.$$

Using $dM=\rho dV$ and $dV=2\pi rdrdz$, the right way to sum up all the mass elements is by applying integration:

$$ M_\omega=\int_{M} \left ( 1-\frac{r^2\omega^2}{c^2} \right )^{-1/2}dM \rightarrow$$

$$M_\omega=2\pi \rho\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} \left ( 1-\frac{r^2\omega^2}{c^2} \right )^{-1/2}rdrdz \rightarrow$$

$$M_\omega=\frac{3c}{4v_R^3} \left [2cv_R-(c^2-v_R^2)\ln{\left | \frac{1+v_R/c}{1-v_R/c} \right |}\right ]M \space,$$

where $v_R=R\omega$ is the equatorial velocity of the ball. I also used $\rho=\frac{M}{4\pi R^3/3}$. Remember that if $v_R$ tends to zero and the ball loses its rotation, the relativistic mass tends to rest mass:

$$\lim_{v_R \rightarrow 0} \frac{3c}{4v_R^3} \left [2cv_R-(c^2-v_R^2)\ln{\left | \frac{1+v_R/c}{1-v_R/c} \right |}\right ]M=M$$